# NSDate doesn't refresh

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

The NSDate in my first view Controller wont refresh until I go to another view controller and then come back to it.  Any idea why that would be?

viewDidLoad:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(fadein) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [timer fire];
```

viewWillAppear:

```
// Date
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
    NSString *dateToday = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [dateLabel setText:dateToday];
    dateLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12];
```

Method:

```
-(void) fadein
{
    dateLabel.alpha = 0;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    dateLabel.alpha = 1;

    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:  Problem solved, thanks to the people below with helpful answers.  Looks like other people that didn't give answers closed the question, but both people that gave answers below worked!**

Comment: You need to show your `fadein` method.

Comment: Is the problem that the same date fades in and out?

Comment: I only have a fadein.  And the fade in animation only works when I manually close the app.  The date only changes when I manually close the app or go to a different view controller and then come "back" to the first view controller with the date.

Comment: Since the `fadein` method does not change the content of `dateLabel`'s text, why should the label refresh? Did you try adding `NSLog` to your `fadein` method to make sure that it gets called periodically?

Comment: I see your problem -- you don't have an NSDate anywhere.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The `dateLabel` text should change upon opening the app if it is a different day.  You know what I mean?  So on Sunday I opened the app, but Monday when I opened the app it still had the Sunday date as the `dateLabel`... until I went to the second view controller and then came back to the first view controller, then it finally caught that it was Monday now

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks for the response!  Can you be any more specific though?

Comment: How do you expect an NSDate to "refresh" (whatever that means) if you don't have one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @HotLicks is saying is `fadeIn` is fine but where are you changing the `UILabel` with the new date? You need to do that to show the changed date right?

```
-(void) fadein
 {
    //just an example. change this to the format in which you are showing your date.
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY"];
    uilabelDate.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    ....

 }
```

**UPDATE:** This is what hopefully worked for @reez - Oh I have got it now. Its not a good Idea to put such functions in `viewWillAppear` as sometimes the view would be cached and this method would not be called. Its better to put this method in `viewDidLoad`. See if that works...

Comment: Thanks for the response Srikar.  I edited my question to show that I have my `NSDate` info in my `viewWillAppear`... does it make sense to have it there?

Comment: Oh I have got it now. Its not a good Idea to put such functions in `viewWillAppear` as sometimes the view would be cached and this method would not be called. Its better to put this method in `viewDidLoad`. See if that works...

Answer (score 1):

> The dateLabel text should change upon opening the app if it is a
>   different day. You know what I mean? So on Sunday I opened the app,
>   but Monday when I opened the app it still had the Sunday date as the
>   dateLabel

From your comment, it looks like you're not refreshing the date when re-opening the app. `viewWillAppear` is not called if you press home button and reopen the app (I hope you're aware that this doesn't close/kill the app). You need to add a call to refreshDate from `AppDelegate`'s `applicationWillEnterForeground:` method.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer, I didn't even think about calling from the `AppDelegate`, I'm going to try it out as a better way to do this!